# Linking static singleton class

Tags: c++, linker, singleton

when i try to link a SIngleton class a get

```
sources/singleton.cpp:8:41: error: no se puede declarar que la función miembro ‘static myspace::Singleton& myspace::Singleton::Instance()’ tenga enlace estático [-fpermissive]
sources/director.cpp:19:35: error: no se puede declarar que la función miembro ‘static void myspace::Singleton::Destroy()’ tenga enlace estático [-fpermissive]
myspace: *** [objects/singleton.o] Error 1
```

the Singleton class:

```
#Singleton.h
#include <stdlib.h>

namespace myspace {

    class Singleton
    {
    public:
        static Singleton& Instance();
        virtual ~Singleton(){};
    private:
        static Singleton* instance;
        static void Destroy();
        Singleton(){};
        Singleton(const Singleton& d){}
    };
}

#Singleton.cpp
#include "../includes/Singleton.h"

namespace myspace {
    Singleton* Singleton::instance = 0;

    static Singleton& Singleton::Instance()
    {
        if(0 == instance) {
            instance = new Singleton();

            atexit(&Destroy);
        }

        return *instance;
    }

    static void Singleton::Destroy()
    {
        if (instance != 0) delete instance;
    }
}
```

i need some LDFLAGS to the linker?

Comment: Tip: When posting here, as well as searching internet, using English error-strings is usually a good idea.

One can temporarily request English output in most POSIX environment by prefixing the command with "LANG=C". So, for example `LANG=C make` would give you a good searchable and postable error-string.

Comment: thanks @Rawler i'm novice in the topic. I'll keep in mind

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove `static` from the *definitions* in the cpp file: the compiler already knows the `Singleton::Instance` and `Singleton::Destroy` are `static` from their *declarations*. Everything else looks right.

Answer (score 7):

You can only declare methods static in the declarations, it's not allowed in the implementations. Just change your implementations to;

```
Singleton& Singleton::Instance()
{
```

and

```
void Singleton::Destroy()
{
```

and you should be fine.